# What is the formula for calculating these probabilities?

Tags: statistics, probability

The probability that you randomly choose a red marble from a bag is is 0.6. A random sample of 6 marbles are drawn from the bag (The sample has an appropriate binomial distribution.)

What is the probability that exactly four of these marbles are red?

What is the probability that two or fewer of these marbles are red?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The probability is according to the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

[image]

So to calculate the probability for 4 red marbles outta 6 from scratch using python, it will be:

```
n = 6
k = 4
p = 0.6

import scipy.special
# the two give the same results 
scipy.special.binom(n, k)*(p**k)*((1-p)**(n-k))

0.31104000000000004
```

We can use the binomial distribution from scipy:

```
from scipy.stats import binom
binom.pmf(4,6,0.6)

0.31104
```

For two or fewer of these marbles are red, basically it's the probability of 0,1,2

```
sum(binom.pmf([0,1,2],6,0.6))
0.17920000000000008
```

Or you can use the cdf:

```
binom.cdf(2,6,0.6)
```